@LdapIdentityStoreDefinition read bindDnPassword from environment variable or property file in WildFly
I am having a challenging time achieving a security common pattern of loading secrets from an environment variable or a properties file. I am tring to load the password of an openLDAP admin user in jakarta-ee annotation @LdapIdentityStoreDefinition
My question is very similar to this Payara container question but for Wildfly.
I havent considered migrating to Payara yet. I am open to migrating since this is my pet project and i had already migrated from Tomcat to Wildfly. I am using docker image Wildfly with JDK 21 quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:32.0.0.Final-1-jdk21
I have tried using multiple options and i have tested with the plain text password and it works. I cannot commit the code with the password in plain sight.
@LdapIdentityStoreDefinition(
        url = "ldap://openldap:389",  // Replace with your server details
        callerBaseDn = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org",
        groupSearchBase = "dc=example,dc=org",
        bindDn = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org",
//        bindDnPassword ="#{login.bindDnPassword}" // bind Distinguished Name
)


#{login.bindDnPassword} is an Expresion Language expression, so by default it resolves to a CDI bean named "login".
If you add a bean, something like:
    @Named("login")
    public class LoginBean {
    
       public String getBindDnPassword() {
           return ... // get password from ENV, file, whatever
       }
    }

Then it should work.

is there a reason why LdapIdentityStoreDefinition.url is the only attribute which doesn't get evaluated?

@XavierDury it actually should be. If it doesn't in a certain implementation it's a bug there.

I encountered that bug in JBoss EAP 7.4.16 which embeds soteria 1.0.1. That problem was resolved for milestone 1.1 which never got released :-/

Indeed, that got fixed here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/soteria/commit/0a63ea3ca74ede06f2c98e8c6beb678ea883b33e
Not that long after we moved to the 2.x series of Soteria. For now it would be Red Hat who can do their own Soteria 1.x release. Alternatively you can compile Soteria yourself from source and update it in JBoss, but since you're using EAP that will likely effect your support.
